# C# windows service copy files before startup

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have a C# windows service which needs to copy files from shared folder like C:\Shared to its own Bin folder C:\MyService\Bin before service starts.

Lets say I have `A.dll` and `B.dll` in `C:\Shared`. The way windows service copies is, in **Main()** of **Program.cs** it reads a file called `MyLibs.txt` which has list of libraries it needs to copy from C:\Shared. So MyLibs.txt will be like below

```
C:\MyService\Bin
MyLibs.txt

A
B
```

After copying the files then it will start the service.

```
static class Program
{
   static void Main()
   {
            
        try
        {
          CopyFiles(); // copy files from C:\Shared. Its long code to share here
          ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
          ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
          {
             new MyService()
          };
          ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
          //handle exception
        }
    }
}
```

When I stop and start my service for some libraries I get below exception

> System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'C:\MyService\Bin\B.dll' because it is being used by another process.

I made sure that service is stopped and I go to Task Manager and under Details tab I make sure that I end my service task. But I still get below exception.

Please let me know what is best way to handle copy files from other folder into Windows Service BIN folder before Windows Service starts.

My issue is with this..

```
System.IO.File.Copy(sourceLibraryFullName, destinationLibraryFullName, true);
```

Comment: you need to first close the processes which use B.dll

Comment: everything is done by C# code. I open services and make sure that my windows service is stopped. In Task Manager also make sure my processes is stopped but I still get that..

Comment: does your service use that dll?

Comment: yes my service needs that.. thats why I stop the service and start the service...

Comment: you can read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/load-unload

Comment: My issue is copy from one folder into others...I do this... System.IO.File.Copy(sourceLibraryFullName, destinationLibraryFullName, true);

Comment: Be sure what process has the handle open.  Use the process monitor and look at the open file handles for that file.

Comment: Your issue is that the app references service and service references B, so your app can't write into B

Comment: Bizhan... can you tell me how to over come it...